# Configuration issue: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [urn:infinispan:config:7.0]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, infinispan

I'm testing infinispan cache embeded mode.
but it occurred in springframework.. but it's ok in stand alone mode...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [urn:infinispan:config:7.0]
Offending resource: file [C:\dev\ide\eGovFrameDev-3.5.1-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\demo\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\spring\com\context-infinispan.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80) ~[spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: It seems a classpath issue, i suggest to you to deploy your app to webapp folder in your application container(i suggest webapp to assume you use tomcat) Also be sure context-infinispan.xml in a place which is in project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this might be caused by a classpath issue or missing schema location (see [this link for reference](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/7.2.5.Final/spring/spring4/src/test/resources/org/infinispan/spring/config/CacheLoaderNotFoundTest-context.xml#L4-L5)).

So, in order to fix this I would advice checking:

- If it deploys correctly to your container (without using IDE)
- check if `xsi:schemaLocation`s are correct

However if it still doesn't work - could you please paste me your Spring configuration XML as well as your pom (ant or gradle file)?